# what is the rule for __r API name?

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template

I have always the same problem when I use apex: repeat

the question is how or where do we find/write  the API name for a plural Label .

I had the same case before with BC (Purchase order) and BC Line Items : 2 objects that I have created .

after testing I found the solution here : [BC case](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81706/please-how-to-retrieve-line-items-to-visualforce-email-template)

on the BC Object where API Name:    BC__c  Plural Label  : BC (Purch. Orders)
on the BC Line item Object , we have on Custom fields :
BC ( BC_c) as a

> Master-Detail(BC (Purch. Order))

and

> Plural Label :    BC Line Items
>   API Name  BC_Line_Item__c

so following the solution on the first link The apex repeat works after doing :

```
 <apex:repeat var="opp" value="{!relatedTo.BC_line_items__r}">  </apex:repeat>
```

now my problem is on Sales Order Level and Sales Order Linte Item .
Plural Label :  Sales Orders
API Name    Sales_Order__c

and on sales Order Line Item :

```
Plural Label    Sales Order Line Items
API Name    Sales_Order_Line_Item__c
```

Sales Order `(Sales_Order__c) Master-Detail(Sales Order)`

when I tested it in different way by writing :

```
<apex:repeat var="opp" value="{!relatedTo.Sales_order_line_items__r}">
```

or `<apex:repeat var="opp" value="{!relatedTo.Sales_Order_Line_Item__r}">`

there is an error `Error: Invalid field Sales_order_line_items__r for SObject Sales_Order__c`

thanks in advance for your response

Comment: it's just master detail relationship API.

Comment: Hi , do you mean on Master-Detail Options  on Sales Order Line item Object . when I checked Master-Detail(Sales Order)  : API Name : Sales_Order__c and on the option Related List Label : Sales Order Line Items

Comment: A standard object gets an `s` appended to its name. A custom object would get the `__r` depending on the context. If someplace in your code, you've isolated the object to where it's now purely that object, it then goes back to `__c`, but if you're iterating from a query on the original object and it's a related object, it would have the `__r`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For custom lookup fields, the developer chooses the name for the relationship. To find the name, look at the field details for the lookup. The property is called the relationship name. It will not include the __r, but you need to include it when referencing the relationship.